# what is cv::setTo function

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a code written using OpenCV in C++, and this code uses a function setTo. Basically, it is used as:

```
cv::Mat xx; //prefedined and has some values
cv::Mat yy; // initially empty

yy.setTo(0,xx);
```

So can you explain what does this setTo means here? Does is put all zero values in yy, or it puts 1 where xx is non-zero and 0 where xx is zero too?

Comment: Indeed the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-setto) is quite obscure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`yy.setTo(0)` will set all the pixels to 0.

`yy.setTo(0, xx)` will set all the pixels who have a corresponding pixel with a non-zero value in the xx `Mat` to 0.

Example:

```
yy =
2 2 2
2 2 2
2 2 2

xx =
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0

yy.setTo(0, xx) =>

yy = 
2 2 2
2 0 2
2 2 2
```

Comment: Correction: The second form will set all the pixels who have a corresponding pixel with a _non-zero_ value in the xx Mat to 0.