# C++ | Change color in cv::mat with setTo

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a cv::Mat file with vec3b values. These values are colours from an image. I'd like to change some colours in that image.

I know the setTo() function for normal matrix manipulation, but how do I use it for my Mat file?

I tried something like this:

```
 image = image.setto(Vec3b(0,0,0), image == Vec3b(255,0,0))
```

Thx!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given an image `image`, we want to find all the pixels in `image` that are equal to `Scalar(255,0,0)` and then set these pixels to `Scalar(0,0,0)`.

- First we need to obtain `mask`, such that a location in `mask` is set to 255 if the corresponding location in `image` equals `Scalar(255,0,0)`, otherwise it is set to 0. This can be achieved with [`inRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=inrange#cv2.inRange) function.

  ```
  Mat mask;
  inRange(image, Scalar(255,0,0), Scalar(255,0,0), mask);
  ```
- Now apply `setTo()` function to `image`.

  ```
  image.setTo(Scalar(0,0,0), mask);
  ```

Comment: Not trying to be pedantic but I don't think you meant to have the keyword "void" before the inRange function, and you missed the semicolon at the end.

Comment: @Alex I thought I saw some syntax one time that was more like `image(image == Scalar(255,0,0)) = Scalar(0,0,0)` but I can't seem to get it to work - does something like that exist?

Comment: @DavidDoria Something like that is the way to go in Matlab. It's not possible yet in OpenCV. See [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id6) for `Mat::opertor()`

Comment: @Alexey great explanation! Thanks a lot. BTW, guys, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8973044/5969121 (can be helpful).