# Copy image changing black pixels into white pixels

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I am reading pictures (`img1=cv2.imread('picture.jpg')`) on which there is only one object, and the background is black.

Note that the object has no black pixels.

I want to copy `img1` to `img2` like this: `img2=img1.copy()` But I want in `img2` to have all the black pixels (backgroun) of `img1` set to white. How can I reach this goal ?

Comment: just floodfill() with white pixels ?

Comment: I will check what i can do with @berak 's suggestion

Comment: what about the foreground pixels of `img1`? Is `img1` a binary image? If it is, then the easiest way to set white of `img1` background pixels over `img2` is the use of [bitwise operators](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=bitwise_and#bitwise-and).

Comment: @Kornel no, it is multicolor (RGB) image

Comment: Related question and answer in C++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981379/c-change-color-in-cvmat-with-setto

Comment: @Antonio Thank you, I will try your solution when I get access to my laptop in few hours then compare with this link. Thank you.

Comment: @Kabyle If you now have a python solution I suggest you post it as an answer (I got your question reopened :) ), or as an edit to your question.

Comment: @Antonio when you program with OpenCV there is not difference if you do it in Python or C++ for the important instructions :)

Comment: @Kabyle Having the python tag is the main reason for which this question is not marked as duplicate of the question I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: *(In C++, see comments below)*

```
const cv::Mat img1=cv::imread('picture.jpg')

///Create a grayscale mask -> only pixel !=0 in the mask will be copied
cv::Mat mask(img1.size(),CV_8U); ///cvtColor requires output image to be already allocated
cv::cvtColor(img1, mask, CV_BGR2GRAY);

///Initialize output image to white
cv::Mat img2(img1.size(),CV_8UC3);
img2.setTo(cv::Scalar(255,255,255) );

///Copy pixels from the original image to the destination image, only where mask pixels != 0
img1.copyTo(img2,mask);
```

Using [copyTo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=copyto#void%20Mat::copyTo%28OutputArray%20m,%20InputArray%20mask%29%20const) and [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor).
The only problem is if within the input image you have pixels at zero out of the background. In that case you might prefer a floodfill approach, but probably is an overkill for your problem.

Edit: You can also use [inRange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20982392/2436175) to create your mask.

Comment: Ok, I will try your solution and let you know later (however I will translate it to Python)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I had missed you were working in Python! But it's good, I wouldn't have answered in that case :) :) Please feel free to post the code once you have the solution.

Comment: If your solution works in C++ I will accept it , do not worry (I am familar with C++, for the moment I just upvoted because your solution looks logic even if I did not test it yet)

Comment: I also found an algorithmic way to do that: loop over the pixels, if a pixel's three channels are set to 0 (black) then set them to 255 :)