# Set specific pixel values of Mat, opencv

Tags: opencv, mat

I know we can set all pixel values, and access each pixel to set values. Suppose I already have a set of pixels, whose value alone, I want to set as say 255. Is this possible, in opencv? Is there a function can do this? Sorry if this question is rudimentary

Comment: Have you tried [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974946/how-to-edit-read-pixel-values-in-opencv-from-mat-variable) ?

Comment: I think the asnwer given was something I was looking for. I already know how to access elements, as  I had mentioned @pwwpche

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971308/what-is-cvsetto-function) gives a better explanation on how to use the function as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [`setTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=setto#mat-setto) function, which allows to set the value of some masked mat elements:

```
Mat& Mat::setTo(InputArray value, InputArray mask=noArray() )
```